# format currency with currency symbol at the front

Tags: c#, format, currency, culture

hi
how to format the currency with euro symbols at the front. A currency formatted with culture fr-Fr results in currency symbols at the end and commas instead of "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CultureInfo` class allows you to determine such settings. Many format methods (e.g. `String.Format()` through the `IFormatProvider` parameter) take a `CultureInfo` as parameter. You can configure a `CultureInfo` instance with your requirements, for example the currency symbol settings which you can set using the `NumberFormat` property.

If you want these settings to apply to the entire user interface, set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and/or the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` property. This setting is picked up by many methods that take a `CultureInfo` as parameter.

Comment: Decimal amount;
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        culture.NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€ ";
        if (Decimal.TryParse(amt, out amount))
            return String.Format(culture, "{0:C}", amount);
        else
            return "-";

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyPositivePattern.
Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx is a table with possible values.
Same is for NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern.